# retrieve the infected respondents or vaccinated respondents and the household in which they belong to and the puroks which their household belongs to

Tags: laravel

I'm still new to pivot tables and eloquent. I have a controller that retrieves the infected respondents with disease and the vaccinated respondents with the vaccine.

I want to display in the views the household_head_id that the respondents belong to. I have a pivot table `respondent_household_heads` for respondents and `hosuehold_heads` and a `puroks` table in which the `household_head` belongs. But I need to learn how to handle complex, eloquent relationships.

**Contoller to retrieve infected and vaccinated respondents:**

```
$infectedRespondents = Respondent::when($selectedDiseaseId, function ($query) use ($selectedDiseaseId, $startDate, $endDate) {
        $query->whereHas('diseases', function ($innerQuery) use ($selectedDiseaseId, $startDate, $endDate) {
            $innerQuery->where('disease_id', $selectedDiseaseId)
                       ->when($startDate && $endDate, function ($dateQuery) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                           $dateQuery->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
                       });
        });
    })
    ->when($selectedVaccineId, function ($query) use ($selectedVaccineId) {
        $query->whereHas('vaccines', function ($innerQuery) use ($selectedVaccineId) {
            $innerQuery->where('vaccine_id', $selectedVaccineId);
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

I want to add here the code on how I can display the household these infected individuals belong to and the `puroks` that their household belongs to.